# Загрузка данных в календарь UI

Tags: jquery-ui, javascript, ui

Доброго всем времени суток. Имееться обычный календарь ui http://floomby.ru/s1/pWpr88 и массив данных:

> [дата, день, месяц, день_недели, название, место_проведения, краткое_описание]

1. Как выделять те дни в календаре, которые имеют какое-то мероприятие.
2. Как сделать так, чтоб по клику на число инфа выводилась в правый блок как на скриншоте.

Если есть у кого готовое решение или кто-нибудь знает как реализовать такую фишку буду благодарен за любую информацию. Спасибо!

Comment: сделайте массив событий, и [когда дата выбрана](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) вставляйте в свой блок с информацией о событии нужную информацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример хэндлера для onSelect [image: демо]

```
var events = {
    '07.05.2014': {
        title: "Чудесный день",
        desc: "Прекрасный день чтобы изучить javascript"
    }
}

function showEvents(date, obj) {
    var eventsDiv = obj.input.siblings('.events');
    if (events[date]) {
        var event = events[date],
            title = $('<div>').addClass('title').text(event.title),
            desc = $('<div>').addClass('desc').text(event.desc);
        eventsDiv.empty().append(title, desc).stop().fadeIn('slow');
        return;
    }
    eventsDiv.stop().fadeOut('slow');
}
```

Comment: То, что доктор прописал)) Спасибо!